# Running app while the device is off

Tags: android

I have a very simple question. Can you force an app (from a development point of view) to run while the phone is off and plugged in. I know with my phone there is a battery display that shows while the phone is off and charging which I assume is controlled by software but I was wondering if that is possible with an app. After research my gut is telling me no but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know with my phone there is a battery display that shows while the phone is off and charging which I assume is controlled by software but I was wondering if that is possible with an app.

This is not possible from an app, only from firmware.

If you are not looking to update the screen, you can use a `WakeLock` to keep the CPU on. Or, use a different `WakeLock` and keep the screen on all of the time. Neither of these will make the user very happy, unless it is done completely under their control.

Answer (score 0):

You will need create Service and on create or when you are about to do whatever your app does, create and acquire [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html). Once it's done you can startForeground to let user know that you are doing some important job and let Android to keep you alive/process and let your app finish work.

Comment: +1 This is a legitimate answer as the question failed to specify which of the many meanings of "off" applies, so screen off but application CPU active is as valid as any other state.  If it were completely "off" *nothing* would be running.

Comment: Not really sure how my answer is so different than one hour later :) nevermind.

Comment: The other answer primarily address the situation where some lowest level housekeeping program is active but the application CPU is either not running at all, or at least not running the linux kernel or any Android code below it.  That's a much more "off" meaning of "off".